# Convert UTC time to desired timezone Angular

Tags: angular, time, timezone, utc, moment-timezone

I know this question is asked several times but Im looking for more specifics.
I would like to convert the UTC time to desired timezone and the timezones I get from the API are in the below format:
(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada), (GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : London, (GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna

And in some cases they are also abbreviated : CEST, PST etc

Im using moment-timezone but unable to figure out the right way of doing this.
Looking for a solution

Cheers

Comment: And what API would that be?

Comment: Its an internal API from my org which stores the timezones of employees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> Its an internal API from my org which stores the timezones of employees

I'm sorry, but there's no possible way we can help you.  You'll need to sync with whomever is responsible for putting data into that system to understand where they got it from and how they intend for you to use it.

In general, some of those strings look *similar* to Windows time zone display names, but once you're into abbreviations all bets are off (CST, IST, and many others have multiple meanings).  There's no magic table that can map them back to something usable.

The best practice for time zone fields in APIs is to use IANA time zone identifiers.  For example, `America/Los_Angeles`, `Europe/London`, etc.  [See the full list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  If your organization's API is returning something else, then that should probably be changed - but you'll have to take that up with them.

Comment: Thanks Matt!! I will take that up with them now that I at-least know there is no right way of using this

Comment: Just another thing, will using the values like GMT-5 etc be helpful to convert the time to intended timezones?

Comment: What you really want is the actual numeric timezone offset in minutes for easy calculations.

Comment: No.  An offset is not the same as a time zone.  This is a very common mistake.  A time zone *has* one or more offsets.  It's a one-to-many relationship - not one-to-one.  Please see the section titled "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  Thanks.

Comment: To clarify - an offset is only good for a particular point in time.  If you have a date, time, and offset together, you don't need any other time zone information.  But what you cannot do is take an offset from one date/time and apply it to a different date/time thinking it will be the same.  It very well may not.